# Changing font and color at run time in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

is there any way to change font size, font color etc properties at run time in crystal report.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rpt;

        ((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["fieldname here"]).Font; // access font here.
```

I think this should give you enough information to do what you want. Just fiddle around with it.

Comment: .ApplyFont(new Font("Arial", 5));?

Comment: thanks it works. but i should mention that ReportObject must be convert to FieldObject not TextObjext. and finally after i tested this method i prefered to use conditional formatting. again thanks for ur clue

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manipulate the formatting programmatically, you can use formulas on the text object to calculate the font family, size, color, etc., or use **Highlighting Expert**.